# Plotly.js chart - no xaxis is shown

Tags: plotly

Here is my example:

[Example](https://codepen.io/MZolotoy/pen/qBEzyRZ)

And code:

```
var trace1 = {
  x: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
  y: [1.5, 1, 1.3, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9],
  type: 'scatter'
};

var trace2 = {
  x: [0, 1, 2, 4, 5],
  y: [1, 0.5, 0.7, 0.3, 0.4],
  type: 'bar',
  base: 0.5,
};

var data = [trace1, trace2];

Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data);
```

Basically, I dont understand why X axis is not shown. Anyone can help?

Adding picture of what I need to have:
[image]

Thanks

Another example:

[Another example](https://codepen.io/MZolotoy/pen/ZEYdMqy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you’re setting the `base` of your bars to 0.5, the y axis range doesn’t include 0 unless you set it explicitly or one of your scatter points has a y value closer to 0.

Comment: That makes sense, although I am not sure I understand what would a use case be for using Base at all. I am showing a picture of what I am trying to achieve.  I also have a message on Plotly forum with more details.

Comment: I am adding another example where I am setting up y axis range. Still doesn't work.

Comment: You can’t just set mydiv.layout.yaxis range like that, you need to either use restyle or put it in the newPlot call.

Comment: I should add that there is a difference between “the axis”, the zero-line and the framing line. The axis is definitely being shown I.e. you are seeing tick labels. The zero-line is out of range so is legitimately not being shown. You can turn on the framing line with `showline` I believe.

Comment: Sorry, above where I wrote restyle I meant relayout :)

Comment: I do have relayout. I have added showline for x axis. The example looks much better now. Thanks for your help.

Comment: However, in my real code it only works if I use yaxis.autorange = false. Any idea what might be wrong with my code?

Comment: This SO question is starting to drift around a lot... can you please try to frame up the specific question you want an answer to and then stick with it so we can try to get a canonical answer recorded and accepted?

Comment: Just so you know, as soon as I got the latest version (1.52) everything started working!!!!

Comment: Unfortunately, even the latest version is not working for negative values. https://community.plot.ly/t/look-like-a-bug/34416